# Allowing user to enter integers for an array, and moving to next step when "-99" is entered

Tags: java

The homework problem I am stuck on requires me to make a program with a loop that lets the user enter a series of integers, and stops the loop when -99 is entered.  Then it should print the largest and smallest numbers entered.

Right now I am stuck trying to make the loop stop when -99 is entered.  I am using an array for the inputted numbers (as this is what we were taught in class most recently).

I have tried using another integer "input" for the scanner input, and then writing that to the array, but this gave me errors.  I tried this because I know that I can use "input != -99;" for the for loop condition.

```java
input = kb.nextInt();
numbers[index] = input;
```

This is where I am at now, which compiles and runs with no errors.

```java
        System.out.println("Enter -99 to end the loop.");{
            for (int index = 0; numbers[index] != -99; index++) {
                System.out.println("Number " + (index+1) + ":");
                numbers[index] = kb.nextInt();
            }
```

When I enter -99 as the next number, it just accepts it as an input and loops  again.

Comment: this is happening because each time you check the index has increased by 1 and checks the next element. You need to use `while` loop here.

Answer (score 0):

Like Zain Arshad the index you put the entered number is incremented that's why your condition your loop don't get the expected result

you can adjust the the condition and put a separate loop break

```
System.out.println("Enter -99 to end the loop.");
for(int index = 0; true; index++){
    System.out.println("Number " + (index+1) + ":");
    numbers[index] = kb.nextInt();
    if(numbers[index] == -99){
        break;
    }
}
```